# IF user is in a certain page/url DO this

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, if-statement

I have a website that the user can read both in Italian and English language.
 
The English website is characterized by the following path: mysite.com/… 
While the Italian one has the following path: mysite.com/it/…
I am now implementing a booking module that should be displayed only in the home and in the “Fares” pages in order to provide the user a tool to reserve a spot for the service I offer (taxi services). The module is connected to a Database containing the cities (departures and arrivals) and the related prices. For module I mean a box where you are asked some information (in my case: Departure, arrival, # of passengers and # of luggages), you press a button and something happen (in my case you query the database getting the price of the trip). 
Since the website has two languages I need to translate both the module and the database as well. I proceeded in the following way:

- I created two folders containing the same module but one is in
  Italian while the other is in English;
- Each module queries the
  correct database, the Italian module takes the data from the Italian
  DB while the English module read the data from the translated one
  (es. Malpensa Aeroporto -> Malpensa Airport).

What I would like to do now is to create an if statement that does the following:

```
IF (on the homepage of mysite.com/) {
Get the English module
} else IF (on the homepage of mysite.com/it/) {
    Get the Italian module
    } else {
    Do nothing because you are not on any homepage
    }
```

I already have searched in the blog and around the internet but I am not able to find something working. How can I develop this "IF statement"? 
Thank you all

Comment: if you were to utilise a `rewrite` rule courtesy of your `.htaccess` file then you could use `$_GET['language']` etc which would in turn mean you would only need one module. As it stands though look at `parse_url` ~ specifically the path `parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_PATH );`

Comment: "I created two folders containing the same module".  So if your Italian folder is named "it" and placed within your root, shouldn't work as-is?

Comment: @PatrickQ unfortunately the "module" is placed in the template folder so it is bounded to every page in the website, both italian and english (and not only for the home pages). That is why I need to find a way to use the IF; also because I need the "do nothing" alternative in the other pages.

Comment: @RamRaider is there a way without modifying other file except for the php ones?

Comment: Is "it" a WordPress page?

Comment: @AndrewSchultz Which "is" do you refer to?

Comment: @Miranda95 check out my answer!

Comment: @Miranda95 what is the slug "it", a page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by this,

```
$explode = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if($explode[1] == 'it'){
    echo 'call Italian';
}else{
    echo 'call English';
}
```

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` contain the path in site.
In my case

`/stack/help.php`

So `explode()` it and then check if the directory name equal to it you call the module for Italian language else call English one.

And this you must call in file included in both
`index.php`, `/it/index.php`

**Or try this**

explode `getcwd()` and use `end()`

```
$directory = explode('/', getcwd());
if( end($directory) == 'it' ){
    //call Italian Module
}else{
    //call English Module
}
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: I will try it as soon as I can! Thank you for it and hope it will work! Let you know the result in 2 days

Comment: Ok, I will check the question when you reply.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! It worked! Unfortunately now I have a different problem XD If you have time check the issue out on the other question I opened. ;)